# about petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find the minimum number of color in Petersen graph with this condition that every vertex with all neighbor have different color ?, I think that because this graph is 3-regular then answer is at least 4 ,but it is not true (from draw graph).

Comment: So the neighbours of a vertex $v$ must all receive different colours, but one of those colours could be the same as the colour of $v$? Is that how this requirement is to be interpreted?

Comment: Different color for vertex and neighbor

Comment: It is not chromatic number.

Comment: I understand it's not the chromatic number. So you want $v$ *and* all its neighbours to have different colours?

Comment: @casteels,Yes exactly

Comment: Are you aware that the Petersen graph has diameter $2$? So your requirement means that all $10$ vertices must have different colors?

Comment: @bof,Yes because every  two disjoint vertex have exactly one common neighbor, then diameter is 2. But I don't know why 10

Comment: Because there are $10$ vertices? And no two vertices can have the same color? So $10$ different colors are needed, one for each vertex? What's the problem?

Comment: Yes because every two vertex can't have same color then answer is 10,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that there is a 3-coloring by providing an example, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#/media/File:Petersen_graph_3-coloring.svg) from the [Petersens Graph Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph)

Comment: Did you read the question? It is asking about vertex colorings that satisfy an additional condition.

Comment: You wrote: "that every vertex with all neighbor have different color". If I understand this correctly it is the main feature of a vertex coloring, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't write that. It isn't my question. Did you read the comments? The question is not stated clearly but the OP explicitly states in one comment that "It is not chromatic number."

Comment: No, I did not read the comments. Sorry.